# Change Font Color of a Row on click event in Primefaces Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to change the font color after clicking a particular row in a datatable. I have already used 
onclick="this.style.color='green'; But it's not persisting. My code is as follows:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{userOption.menus}" var="mn" id="dt" paginator="true" rows="10">
 <p:column>
    <h:commandLink action="#{userOption.ret(mn.menuid)}" onclick="this.style.color='green';" update="p1:dt">
        #{mn.menuname}
    </h:commandLink>
 </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: can u post your output image?

Comment: Did you search for solution? You can easily find a few examples of javascript, which set some decoration on datatable selected row

Answer (score 0):

Your code for changing color `onclick` is fine.
The main problem here is `h:commandLink`.

Because every time you click the `h:commandLink`, it doesn't send the Ajax(POST) request, instead it submits the entire form with GET request.

So from your code the color is changing but since its a `h:commandLink` entire `p:dataTable` is re-rendered and color is rest back.

To solve this you can use Primefaces `p:commandLink`, which sends a AJAX(POST) request every time you click, so Entire `p:dataTable` is not re-rendered and your style changes applied from `onclick` will persist.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{userOption.menus}" var="mn" id="dt" paginator="true" rows="10">
 <p:column>
    <p:commandLink action="#{userOption.ret(mn.menuid)}" onclick="this.style.color='green';" update="p1:dt">
        #{mn.menuname}
    </p:commandLink>
 </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem with h:commandLink and put an onclick method and its working consistently.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{files.fileName}" onclick="changeLink(this);" id="fetchPdf" action="#{bean.fetchPdf}" target="_blank"/>

<script>
    function changeLink(el){
        el.style.color = 'purple';
    }
</script>
```